# Improving visualization of geometric shapes

Tags: c++, vtk

I have been using VTK for a month and I noticed that it is the best visualization tool. For my PhD, I am trying to visualize hundreds of ellipsoids and some point clouds using VTK. So far, I visualized ellipsoids and point clouds successfully as shown in the attached figure. However, it has to be developed. Without some shading and lighting effects it is impossible to distinguish individual ellipsoids (shown by green). For example, there are a few ellipsoids at upper left but they cannot be distinguished. Could you please help me about this problem? How can I make them distinguishable?
I am looking forward to hearing from you. [image: Elipsoids and point cloud]

Comment: Have you tried to add a border?

Answer (score 0):

You can use silhouettes for distinguishing objects. Please find attached bellow a code demonstrating extracting and visualizing silhouettes using the `vtkPolyDataSilhouette` class.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataSilhouette> silhouette = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataSilhouette>::New( );
silhouette->SetInputData( surface->GetOutput( ) );
silhouette->SetCamera( renderer->GetActiveCamera( ) );
silhouette->SetEnableFeatureAngle( 1 );
silhouette->SetFeatureAngle( 90 );

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> silhouetteMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New( );
silhouetteMapper->SetInputConnection( silhouette->GetOutputPort( ) );
silhouetteMapper->Update( );

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> silhouetteActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New( );
silhouetteActor->SetMapper( silhouetteMapper );

renderer->AddActor( silhouetteActor );
```

Another way is extracting and visualizing contours using the `vtkContourFilter` class. Here you can find an example how to use the class: https://itk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/ExternalContour

Comment: I used diffuse color property and it is much more better now. By the way, I tried vtkPolyDataSilhouette class but I got error message that vtkParametricSuperEllipsoid class does not support GetOutput( ) metfod.